# How to concurrently run ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: java, multithreading, scheduler

I have a program that periodically checks for new data from a web page and then downloads and converts it into another format. Because the download of one dataset consists mostly of waiting, the program can be sped up by processing one dataset while downloading another, thus I want to use multi threading. Unfortunately, ScheduledThreadpoolExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate() blocks until one Runnable is finished, even if I set the executor constructor parameter `corePoolSize` to more than 1. As a workaround, I queued the same Runnable twice but is there a more elegant solution?

```
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Downloader
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor e = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(4);
        e.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Scheduler(), 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        e.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Scheduler(), 1, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you don't want to use separate threads for processing and downloading ?

Comment: What I said was a bit of a simplification. There is download, conversion and upload and restructuring the program would take more time than I have, at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

Separate the task into two sub-tasks and schedule those separately on their own thread pools.

You could have *X* threads performing download tasks and queuing work onto a job queue and *Y* processing threads that dequeue work items and process them.